# Gridview is not populating using databind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following ASP gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TEXT" HeaderText="TEXT" SortExpression="TEXT" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="session_id" HeaderText="session_id" SortExpression="session_id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="status" SortExpression="status" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="command" HeaderText="command" SortExpression="command" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="cpu_time" HeaderText="cpu_time" SortExpression="cpu_time" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="total_elapsed_time" HeaderText="total_elapsed_time" SortExpression="total_elapsed_time" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="dbname" HeaderText="dbname" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="dbname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="user_running_query" HeaderText="user_running_query" SortExpression="user_running_query" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

In the code behind I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            using (Repository.SqldbAllQueries())
            {
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }    
        }
```

And my Repository class contains:

```
public static class Repository
    {
        public static SqlDataReader SqldbAllQueries()
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=sqldb;Initial Catalog=ReportServer;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader;

            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT sqltext.TEXT,req.session_id,req.status,req.command,req.cpu_time,
                                req.total_elapsed_time,DB_NAME(req.database_id) as dbname,s.login_name as user_running_query
                                FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
                                CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext 
                                INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON req.session_id = s.session_id";

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;            
            sqlConnection1.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            return reader;
        }        
    }
```

I am attempting to capture every currently running query on the sql databse and output in in my ASP page as a grid view using the databind method, the code builds and runs however the gridview does not present itself on the page. I have stepped through the code and I can see that `reader` contains rows, but I seem to missing something here as they are not being added to the gridview, can anyone see the problem?

Comment: before `DataBind` you need setup `DataSource` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one,

in **pageload**

```
 GridView1.DataSource = Repository.SqldbAllQueries();
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: GridView1 does not exist in the Repository's context

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Actually if you return reader, you may get an exception.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
    db.FetchData(BindData);
}

private void BindData(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    DataGridView1.DataSource = reader;
    DataGridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And here the DBAccess class(which is similar to Repository class)

```
public void FetchData(Action<SqlDataReader> bindMethod)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Query", sqlConnection))
        {
            bindMethod.Invoke(sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this code helps.